# Find the unique values in a column and then sort them

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, unique

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to print the unique values of one of its columns in ascending order. This is how I am doing it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,2,6,2,8]})
a = df['A'].unique()
print a.sort()
```

The problem is that I am getting a `None` for the output.

Comment: `a.sort()` modifies `a` and does not return anything so replace by: `a.sort(); print a`

Comment: Note: `unique()` returns a numpy.ndarray, so `sort()` is actually `numpy.ndarray.sort()` method. That's why the behavior is unexpected. `drop_duplicates()` returns a pandas series or dataframe, allowing use of `sort_values()`.

Answer (score 382, accepted):

[`sorted(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted): Return a new sorted list from the items in *iterable*.

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,2,6,2,8]})
a = df['A'].unique()
print(sorted(a))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
```

Comment: This doesn't work if your column contains data with ambiguous boolean values, such as pandas' NAType - sorted() will raise a TypeError

Answer (score 49):

[`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort.html#pandas.Series.sort) sorts inplace so returns nothing:

```
In [54]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,2,6,2,8]})
a = df['A'].unique()
a.sort()
a

Out[54]:
array([1, 2, 3, 6, 8], dtype=int64)
```

So you have to call `print a` again after the call to `sort`.

Eg.:

```
In [55]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,2,6,2,8]})
a = df['A'].unique()
a.sort()
print(a)

[1 2 3 6 8]
```

Comment: The reason is because `unique()` returns a numpy.ndarray, so `sort()` is actually `numpy.ndarray.sort()` method. That's why the behavior is unexpected. `drop_duplicates()` returns a pandas series or dataframe, allowing use of `sort_values()`.

Answer (score 37):

You can also use the [drop_duplicates()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.Series.drop_duplicates) instead of unique()

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,2,6,2,8]})
a = df['A'].drop_duplicates()
a.sort()
print a
```

Comment: Found `drop_duplicates()` to be 3 times faster than unique() on a dataframe of 14107693 rows [Pandas 0.18]

Comment: `df['A'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()` is my favorite

Answer (score 21):

## Faster code

for large data frames:

```
df['A'].drop_duplicates().sort_values()
```

Comment: This answer would be more interesting if you provide the evidence for your claim

Comment: `drop_duplicates()` is better than `unique()` because it can work with multiple cols (dataframes), not just single cols (series).

Comment: Not the fastest code. Try it against `sorted(df.A.unique())`. It's better than `df.A.sort_values().unique()` but certainly not the fastest code.

Answer (score 15):

Came across the question myself today. I think the reason that your code returns 'None' (exactly what I got by using the same method) is that

```
a.sort()
```

is calling the sort function to mutate the list a. In my understanding, this is a modification command. To see the result you have to use print(a).

My solution, as I tried to keep everything in pandas:

```
pd.Series(df['A'].unique()).sort_values()
```

Comment: I like the `pandas` solution because it puts `NaN` values at the end and works with arrays of mixed types.

Answer (score 14):

I prefer the oneliner:

```
print(sorted(df['Column Name'].unique()))
```

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest using numpy's sort, as it is anyway what pandas is doing in background:

```
import numpy as np
np.sort(df.A.unique())
```

But doing all in pandas is valid as well.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is using ***set*** data type.

**Some characteristic of *Sets*:** Sets are unordered, can include mixed data types, elements in a set cannot be repeated, are mutable.

Solving your question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,2,6,2,8]})
sorted(set(df.A))
```

The answer in **List** type:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no one suggested this:

```py
df['A'].sort_values().unique()
```

Comment: Well, yes this works, but it doesn't make sense to do the sorting first (on the entire array) instead of last (on the reduced set). That's why every other answer does `set` -> `sort`.

Comment: Oh yeah it isn't as efficient. Looks cleaner but runs less well.