# Most efficient way of retrieving unique elements from a Pandas column?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, datetime, series

I have a pandas column of datetime objects, and from this column I want to extract a list of unique **years** from it. What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

edit: Wasn't sure how the order of performing the operations was treated by pandas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the unique values in a column and then sort them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072076/find-the-unique-values-in-a-column-and-then-sort-them) -- provided you know how to extract the year from a datetime which you can get from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146121/extracting-just-month-and-year-from-pandas-datetime-column-python).

Comment: @pault I have to disagree. First, getting the years from a datetime column adds a syntactic complexity over the question you link. Second, the question is how to do so *efficiently*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.dt.year` followed by `pd.Series.unique`.

Timings on Python 3.6 / Pandas 0.19 below using data from @Engineero.

```
%timeit df['time'].dt.year.unique().tolist()                  # 739 µs per loop
%timeit df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.year).unique().tolist()  # 5.9 ms per loop
%timeit list(set(df['time'].dt.year.values))                  # 823 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

If you consider the speed , data from Engineero

```
list(set(df['time'].dt.year.values))
```

Answer (score 3):

I made an example that gives us 1000 rows covering 165 years:

```
base = datetime.today()
date_list = [base + x*timedelta(days=60) for x in range(0, 1000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'times': date_list})
```

Trying a bunch of different options and listing them in order from fastest to slowest(ish):

- Using `dt.year.unique()` directly on the `times` column:

  ```
  df.times.dt.year.unique()
  398 µs ± 5.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
  ```
- Using `set` with `dt.year.values` we get about the same performance as `dt.year.unique()`, but with greater variability:

  ```
  set(df.times.dt.year.values)
  422 µs ± 34.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
  ```
- Using `apply`:

  ```
  df.times.apply(lambda x: x.year).unique()
  5.51 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
  ```
- Using `set` and a list comprehension:

  ```
  years = set([time.year for time in df.times])
  3.48 ms ± 68.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
  ```
- Interestingly, using the almost syntactically identical set and a generator, we get something closer to `df.apply`:

  ```
  years = set((time.year for time in df.times))
  5.85 ms ± 198 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
  ```
- And using `np.unique` with a list comprehension:

  ```
  np.unique([time.year for time in df.times])
  6.09 ms ± 130 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
  ```

It looks like, at least on my machine, **`df.times.dt.year.unique()`** is the fastest so far. If I think of others I will add them to the list.